# Search field issues - Doesn't submit on enter, changes url but doesn't load url

Tags: javascript, html

In the following code two things are happening...
When pushing enter it doesn't submit
When I manually click the icon to initiate the `onclick` it changes the url but doesn't load the url.

```js
    function searchKeyPress(e)
    {
        // look for window.event in case event isn't passed in
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode == 13)
        {
            document.getElementById('btnSearch').click();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
                function onClickHandler() {
                    var id ="WordpressEmployeeSearch"
                    var employeeSearchParams = document.getElementById('EmployeeName').value;
                    var cityStateZip = document.getElementById('CityStateZip').value;
                    window.history.pushState([id], id, `/app/?attorney=${employeeSearchParams }&location=${cityStateZip}`);
                }
```

```html
    <div class="tab-area">
        <div class="tabs">
            <p class="tab employee" href="#">EMPLOYEE RATINGS</p>
            <p class="tab company" href="#">COMPANY RATINGS</p>
        </div>
        <div class="search-area">
            <div class="search-bar-area" style="">
                <div class="srch-bars">
                    <input class="home-src" id="EmployeeName" placeholder="Search by Employee's Name" />
                    <input class="state-zip" id="CityStateZip" placeholder="City, State, Zip" />
                  
                </div>
                <div class="icon" id="btnSearch" onClick="onClickHandler()">
                    <i name="Search" class="fas fa-search"></i>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire point of `pushState` is that it changes the URL **without** loading a new page.

It is how you say "I am modifying the DOM if the current page with JavaScript. This gives the same results as if you visited this URL directly, so update the address bar and the history so back/forward/refresh still work".

If you want to navigate to a new page, then use `location = "the new url"`.

Better yet, given the URL you are constructing, remove the JavaScript entirely and just use a regular form submission.

Comment: Thanks for your help. We are using an icon as the onClickHandler. Do you know how to envoke this using the enter button.

Comment: @ThomasA. — Use a regular form with `<button><img src="icon.png" alt="submit"></button>` to submit it. Enter support comes built in as standard.